# Force the use of "old-style" file dialogs in programs?

Tags: windows-7

Is there any way to force programs on my computer to use "old-style" (pre-Vista) open/save dialogs?
(i.e. the one without the toolbar and such.)

[image]

I like those better, and they are faster on my machine.

Comment: I added a screenshot, is that the type of dialog you're after?

Answer (score 0):

The Places Bar box I believe is a Windows 2000 artifact.

The only way to do this that I know of is to either write a shim or modify your System files. The Applications themselves determine which version of the Open/Save dialog box that they choose to open, since Windows supports multiple versions.

I know there is software out there that will replace the Open/Save dialog box.  I have never used any and thus cannot recommend them myself.

Comment: Oh, good point -- that was a typo on my part. I didn't mean the places bar, I meant the toolbar. No idea why I got them mixed up, but will fix.

Comment: Either way, the answer still stands. The application is allowed to choose which style open/save dialog box it wants to call. Short of writing a shim or a resource hacker, I know of no other way around it.